# grails list not returning all, even with no max/offset specified, in g:sortableColumn

Tags: grails

Background: The g:sortableColumn tag by default invokes the list action in a controller, passing it a "sort" parameter, which indicates which field to sort by.   In my specific case, I have an Issue class/list that I'm sorting:

```
 class Issue {
     String title 
          ...
     User assignedTo
          ...
  }
```

and

```
 Class User {
    String lastName
     ...
 }
```

Specifying a g:sortableColumn property="assignedTo.lastName", which translates into the sort parameter of the list, works great if the issue has been assigned -- i.e. assignedTo is non null.  But if it hasn't, then list() no longer returns it.  I don't know if this is a fault of list() or not (comments?), but I'd like to have those Issues with a null assignedTo come at the end.

I thought about combining Issue.list() with an Issue.findAllByAssignedToIsNull(), but it will require coordinating max/offset in both, which I'd rather avoid if possible.

Thoughts/comments?

------- per comment ------

It is the standard (Grails 1.3.7) scaffolded list action, i.e.:

```
   def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    [issueInstanceList: Issue.list(params), issueInstanceTotal: Issue.count()]
}
```

----- per second comment (mine) ----------------------------------------

I also tried the following, once again it did not return the Issues where assignedTo was null:

```
 <g:sortableColumn property="assignedTo.lastName" title="${message(code: 'issue.assignedTo.label', default: 'Assigned To')}" />

 def list = {
   if (params.sort == 'assignedTo.lastName') {
      println "doing special find/sort by: ${params.sort}"
      return [issueInstanceList: Issue.findAllByAssignedToIsNullOrAssignedToIsNotNull(params), issueInstanceTotal: Issue.count()]
   }
   [issueInstanceList: Issue.list(params), issueInstanceTotal: Issue.count()]
 }
```

Comment: can you show us the piece of code, that is retrieving data from database?

Comment: I tried something else that didn't work either, perhaps surprisingly, or is it the same problem?  Included in issue above at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to force a left join on the user table.  Here's one way to do it with a criteria query:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

...

def list() {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    def criteriaParams = [:]
    criteriaParams.putAll(params)
    def sortParam = criteriaParams.remove('sort')
    def orderParam = criteriaParams.remove('order')
    def issueList = Issue.createCriteria().list(criteriaParams) {
        createAlias('assignedTo', 'assignedTo', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        if (sortParam) {
            order(sortParam, orderParam)
        }
    }

    [issueInstanceList: issueList, issueInstanceTotal: issueList.getTotalCount()]
}
```

Passing `params` into the criteria `list()` method automatically handles pagination and sorting, just like the domain object `list()` method.  Our `createAlias` happens too late though, so we have to remove `sort` and `order`, then reapply them manually after creating an alias forcing the left join.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works.     If helpful/related, please note my other attempt above (at end of issue), that didn't work either, in case there is a fix needed in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood g:sortableColumn does not depend on bean object (in this case class User), but uses it's class properties.

`property="assignedTo.lastName"`

always have to be work, because of it is used in 'order by' and 'sort' statements of query

Comment: Jenk, thanks for your response.  I didn't understand the last sentence, could you please clarify?

Comment: i am sorry. i misunderstood a question.